# Leave to enter UK for 6 months

Tags: schengen

Is Brazilian citizen granted a 6 months leave to enter UK, entitled to leave and re-enter in UK during the authorized period and mainly can he/she enter or travel other European country of the European community?

Comment: I can't find any reference at the moment but I doubt you are *entitled* to re-enter. Border guards can always re-evaluate your situation when you present yourself at the UK border.

Answer (score 1):

### Brazil doesn't need a visa for the UK and Schengen Zone

The UK is not part of the Schengen zone. As a [Brazilian for tourism](https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa/y/brazil/tourism) purposes you can get 6 months to visit the UK without a visa. You also do not need a [Schengen visa](http://www.theschengenvisa.co.uk/do-i-need-a-visa) to travel within the Schengen zone. Some European countries are not part of the [Schengen zone](http://www.diplomatie.gouv.fr/en/coming-to-france/getting-a-visa/article/list-of-schengen-area-member).

### How long can you stay?

Every time you enter the UK it is counted as a separate visit with a new 6 month allowed stay stamp on your passport. You can only stay within the [Schengen zone for 90 days in a 180 period](http://travel.state.gov/content/passports/english/go/schengen-fact-sheet.html), regardless of leaving and entering again.

### Will you be allowed into the UK or a European Country?

You are never *entitled* to have access to any country, the border country (UKBA in the UK's case) will ask you questions and assess the purpose of your visit and whether to let you in or not.

Generally as a rule of thumb it would be wise to bring onward travel and proof of accommodation. Also bringing proof of funds would be useful. The UK border is a tough one, so to be safe bring extra documentation.

Comment: This does not seem to address the question, I assume the OP knows all that.

Comment: @Annoyed Thanks for telling me. I re-read the question, and have updated my answer to fix it. Have to admit the travel stackexchange is a lot more friendly than stackoverflow.

Comment: +1 I think the second part is what the OP is after. I also remember it that way but would you have any reference to back that up by any chance?

Comment: I don't have a reference for the UK 6 month new stamp rule, but I know from my girlfriend getting 6 stamps each saying 6 months in the same year.